# How to access a array in a instance

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a card game and I have the following section of code (a small excerpt):

---

```
Hand[] hands;

hands = new Hand[t];

for (i = 1; i > t; i++) {
    hands[i] = new Hand();
}
```

---

```
public class Hand {

    Hand() {
        Card[] hand;

        hand = new Card[52];
    }
}
```

---

How would I access the array in the `Hand` object?

For example, let's say I had a instance of the `Hand` class called `hand1`, how would I access the array `hand` in the `hand1` object?

Doing `hand1.hand[x]` did not work.

Comment: Make it public instead of package-local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Hand() {
    Card[] hand;

    hand = new Card[52];
}
```

Card[] hand is a local variable as you're declaring it inside the Hand() constructor. If you want to use this variable then you should declare it globally like so:

```
private Card[] hand;
  Hand() {
    hand = new Card[52];
}
```

And have getter & setter methods to retrieve that private variable *(this is called 'encapsulation')*. I don't think there's any need to get into those

Comment: Making it `private` without any public/protected/default getter won't work ;)

Comment: @Mik378 Sorry, I sometimes forget to add the obvious

Answer (score 2):

> Doing `hand1.hand[x]` did not work.

You are declaring your "field" in the constructor.

You have to declare it **outside** otherwise it would simply be a local variable.

```
public class Hand {
     Card[] hand;

     Hand() {
       hand = new Card[52];
    }
}
```

However, I presume you know encapsulation so I don't start this subject.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a getter and a setter :

```
public Card getCard (int i)
    throws SomeException()
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= hand.length)
        throw new SomeException();
    return hand[i];
}

public void setCard (Card theCard, int i)
    throws SomeException()
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= hand.length)
        throw new SomeException();
    hand[i] = theCard;
}
```

Of course, you should add range checks for i.

In addition, as Mik correctly commented, define the hand in the correct place (outside the constructor) :

```
public class Hand {
    private Card[] hand;
    Hand() {
        hand = new Card[52];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that even with getter/setter, it would not work... see my answer

Comment: I would not say "you should define getter" but "you may define getter", regarding the OP.

Comment: @Mik378 I say "should", since that's the good practice in OOP. The fact that Java doesn't force you to do it doesn't mean you don't have to.

Comment: IMO, a good OOP practice is to avoid any getter when possible and it's often possible ;)http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter  Setter/getter are still a procedural flow in 95% of cases.